# Why this code generates the error: Heap has been corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Using visual studio 2013, I've been trying to run the code below, but somehow I'm getting a "Heap has been corrupted" exception when the variable vertexPointer reach the number 7172.
Sometimes I get an error: "igdusc32.pdb not loaded"

Help me please !!

```
#define VERTEX_COUNT 128
#define TERRAIN_SIZE 800

int count = VERTEX_COUNT * VERTEX_COUNT;
    int size3 = count * 3;
    int size2 = count * 2;
    float* vertices = (float*)malloc(size3);
    float* normals = (float*)malloc(size3);
    float* uvs = (float*)malloc(size2);

int vertexPointer = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<VERTEX_COUNT; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<VERTEX_COUNT; j++){

        vertices[vertexPointer*3] = (float)j / ((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * TERRAIN_SIZE;
        vertices[(vertexPointer * 3) +1] = 0.0f;
        vertices[(vertexPointer * 3) + 2] = (float)i / ((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * TERRAIN_SIZE;

        normals[vertexPointer * 3] = 0.0;
        normals[(vertexPointer * 3) +1] = 1.0f;
        normals[(vertexPointer * 3) + 2] = 0.0f;

        uvs[vertexPointer * 2] = (float)j / ((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1);
        uvs[(vertexPointer * 2)+1] = (float)i / ((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1);

        vertexPointer++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allocating e.g. `vertices` as `size3` **bytes**, but you need to allocate `size3` **floats**. So change to:

```
float* vertices = (float*)malloc(size3 * sizeof(float));
float* normals = (float*)malloc(size3 * sizeof(float));
float* uvs = (float*)malloc(size2 * sizeof(float));
```

Or, this being C++, use `new` instead:

```
auto vertices = new float[size3];
auto normals = new float[size3];
auto uvs = new float[size2];
```

(and your cleanup would then have to change to `delete[] vertices`, etc).

You can also use `std::vector<float>` which is even more preferable.

```
std::vector<float> vertices(size3);
std::vector<float> normals(size3);
std::vector<float> uvs(size2);
```